Is there a US immigration related Stack Exchange site?
I found a question about whether there is a Stack Exchange site suitable for US immigration related questions, and the answers indicated no, there isn't. But that was 11 years ago. Any updates?

I've seen similar questions answered on Travel.

As of 2014, we have Expatriates Stack Exchange, which might be suitable for some/most of the questions you might have - depending on the question, a long-term stay may have different consequences than a permanent migration.

Expatriates Stack Exchange is for people living or intend to live abroad on a long-term basis, and for questions surrounding ordinary life, just complicated by your status as an expatriate.

From their Help Center article What topics can I ask about here? - please read the entire article, and make sure to search whether your question has already been asked before.
